# How to add product price to wp_query WooCommerce

Tags: php, woocommerce

I am using this code below to display my products on a page.

All works fine but now i need to add in code so the products will show the price and add to cart option.

Can anyone advise what i am missing?

```php
<div class="pro-slider">            

    <div class="pro-items">
        <?php $querys = new WP_Query(array('post_type' => 'product', 'posts_per_page' => -1 )); ?>
        <?php while ( $querys->have_posts() ) : $querys->the_post(); ?>
        <?php $categories = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'product_cat' ); ?>
        <div class="item all <?php echo esc_html( $categories[0]->slug );?>">
            <div class="in">
                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="fimg">
                <?php $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( get_the_ID() ), 'single-post-thumbnail' );?>
                    <?php //the_post_thumbnail('full'); ?>
                    <img src="<?php  echo $image[0]; ?>" alt="image">
                </a>
                <h2 class="t-<?php echo esc_html( $categories[0]->slug );?>"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php endwhile; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
    </div> 
    <div id="probox" class="clearfix"></div>

</div>
```